# Can we use roundcube, thunderbird or any webmail in our xampp/wamp server?

Tags: xampp, localhost, wamp, thunderbird, roundcube

I have a web application developed in PHP and all users can access it via local network(xampp), now the users want to access their gmail,yahoo or any emails via localhost(xampp), I want something like MS-outlook to work in my xampp.
is there any solution ?

Comment: Nowhere near enough information in the question. Access what email? Is this email created by your web site? Where is this email sent, by this i mean is it held on a local mail server? etc etc etc

Comment: Thank you RiggsFolly , I want something like MS-Outlook to be configured in my xampp or wamp. I tried roundcube and thunderbird webmails but could not succeeded , am i going to the wrong way or what?

Comment: I dont understand how a webmail system is related to your web site? Why is Thunderbird not good enough to read Yahoo and gmail?

Answer (score 0):

the propper way to do this is if you use email server at localhost better already install apache2 in your own device

also using postfix and dovecot will be very helpfull here some link
about webmail configuration in google cloud instance

https://medium.com/geekculture/how-to-host-a-personal-email-server-on-google-cloud-for-free-part-i-8124d65d1d25

perhaps that concept will help you to develop your own webmail in Local Area Network